# How common is it for celebrities, influencers etc. to endorse politicians in exchange for money in the US?

Tags: united-states, endorsement

*The Hill* quotes Trump [saying](https://thehill.com/homenews/campaign/4327173-trump-desantis-evangelical-leader-endorsement-2024/):

> “Anyone who would take $95,000, and then endorse a Candidate who is going nowhere, is not what Elections are all about!”

Is this a common practice in the US, for politicians to buy endorsements from celebrities or other influential people with outright cash?

Comment: It is the key business model of influencers to take money from anyone and spread their message afterwards.

Comment: @quarague - Sure, and it's the business model of assassins to take money from anyone and kill somebody afterwards.  The question is, is it a _common practice_ in the US for politicians to make use of such services.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this a common practice in the US, for politicians to buy
> endorsements from celebrities or other influential people with
> outright cash?

No.

This is vanishingly rare in modern U.S. politics. It almost never happens. Endorsements are often traded for policy concessions from the person endorsed, and even sometimes, for non-binding promises to hire the endorser, or their protégé, in the candidate's administration if elected. But endorsements are virtually never traded for cash from the candidate (or the candidate's campaign) given to the endorser.

The usual arrangement is for an endorsement to be part of a package that also includes the endorser providing money to the candidate as a campaign contribution.

This wasn't always the case. In the era of [political machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_machine), voters and influential people often did sell their votes and endorsements. The most famous example involved  Tammany Hall buying support from immigrant voters and leaders in those communities, in New York City in the late 19th century. But the last political machines, in this sense, ceased to exist in U.S. politics roughly sixty years ago when Trump was a teenager. Chicago's was one of the last of them.

Answer (score 2):

Openly trading an endorsement for money is not very likely. This is likely done secretly - in which case there is no public evidence available, beyond some well-publicized scandals (like [Xerox affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_affair) in Russia or Nicholas Sarkozy's [Bygmalion scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_for_a_Popular_Movement#Bygmalion_Scandal).)

What is more commonplace are various "laundering schemes", where money is paid under a legitimate pretext, but effectively means an endorsement. E.g., a popstar performing at a rally held in support of a candidate is effectively endorsing them - many famous names come to mind here, some even campaigning side-by-side with a candidate... but I struggle to find the reliable information on the fees they were paid. Holding a fundraising dinner for a candidate is another common scheme.

It is also worth keeping in mind that celebrities and influences are perpetually running their own publicity campaigns, where they may gain from endorsing popular or unorthodox politicians - likely considered attractive to the public interested in the celebrity, or falling in line with their public image.