# Is it illegal to pay someone to endorse a political candidate?

Tags: united-states, campaigning, freedom-of-speech, campaign-finance, endorsement

If the DNC paid money to Taylor Swift, Usher, or Patrick Mahomes to shout "I'm voting for Biden!" during the Superbowl, would that be illegal/violate any election laws? They're not directly paying for someone to vote a certain way, only to publicly endorse them (like how one might pay for a celebrity to endorse a product in a commercial).

Similarly, would it be allowed for a celebrity to reach out to a political party/candidate and say "hey, I'll publicly shoutout your candidate, but you have to wire X amount into my bank account"?

Comment: If this is a hypothetical, you might want to use other examples, or no names at all. Given the wild rumors floating around, this could be interpreted as an attempt to spread those rumors.

Comment: Related: [How common is it for celebrities, influencers etc. to endorse politicians in exchange for money in the US?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/82899/26455).

Comment: Probably not outright illegal given the answer(s) to the linked Q. But it seems be a bit outside the Overton window in the US right now.

Comment: The FEC rules [here](https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/making-disbursements-ssf-or-connected-organization/endorsing-candidates-corporation-labor-organization/) are essentially silent on the matter (of the campaign paying [something] for the endorsements.) I'm not sure if there's any other FEC rule touching on that.

Comment: @RickSmith - Basically, the non-politicians whose endorsements could conceivably influence an election tend to be very rich, well-known, and conceited. Rich, so it would take a *lot* of money to get their attention (they aren't endorsing anyone for a mere million dollars); well-known, so they could not easily get away with taking such a payment (if Taylor Swift endorsed Donald Trump tomorrow, there would be a *lot* of questions); and conceited, so even if offered a lot of money, they might stick with their opinions out of sheer moral conviction.